# Email address as a parameter in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

```
PageReference retURL = new PageReference('/OrderHistoryguest?orderNumber='+sapOrderNumber +'&email='+userEmailAddress);
```

when i have passing email by apex class to vf page as a url parameter its value change like @ change to some other code So please help me for this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. Some characters are reserved in URL schema, and therefore will be converted to other expressions. It should also be converted back for you automatically. That said, it's better to use EncodingUtil.urlEncode to avoid any surprises.

```
PageReference retURL = new PageReference('/OrderHistoryguest?orderNumber='+sapOrderNumber +'&email='+
  EncodingUtil.urlEncode(userEmailAddress,'utf-8'));
```